# How to select records based on 2 dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, where-clause

i have a table tbl_remit.

```
|RemitNo|id|emp|emp_loc|  emp_cat |ap_from| ap_to |amount|
|   1   |1 | a |  PAL  |  PRIVATE |12/2015|12/2015| 50.00|
|   2   |1 | a |  PAL  |  PRIVATE |01/2016|01/2016|100.00|
|   3   |1 | a |  PAL  |  PRIVATE |02/2016|02/2016|100.00|
|   4   |2 | b |  BTG  |GOVERNMENT|01/2016|01/2016|200.00|
|   5   |2 | b |  BTG  |GOVERNMENT|02/2016|02/2016|200.00|
|   6   |3 | c |  MAR  |  PRIVATE |12/2015|12/2015| 50.00|
|   7   |3 | c |  MAR  |  PRIVATE |01/2016|01/2016|100.00|
|   8   |3 | c |  MAR  |  PRIVATE |02/2016|02/2016|100.00|
```

I need to create a view_ap2015below and select the total/sum of all remittance from the year 2015 and below and where emp_cat is private and group it by emp_loc.

I need to get this table.

```
|emp_loc|  emp_cat |amount|
|  PAL  |  PRIVATE | 50.00|
|  MAR  |  PRIVATE | 50.00|
```

I used this statement but the year 2016 remittance is still there.

```
SELECT Emp_loc, Emp_Cat, FORMAT(SUM(Amount),2) As Amount
FROM tbl_remit
WHERE AP_from <= '01/01/2015' AND AP_To <= '01/01/2015' AND Emp_Cat = 'PRIVATE'
GROUP BY Emp_Loc
```

Is it because the AP_From and AP_To Format of the date is only Month and Year?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be using `Date` datatype to store dates.

Comment: What is the logic by which the amount `50.00` appears in the expected result set?

Comment: I have 72,000 records of employers Remittance. We need to know how much remittance of all PRIVATE company paid with the applicable period of 2015below. It's just an example. should i add more records for the example?

Comment: what is your ap_from and ap_to column's type? I think that these are not date because `12/2015` is not a date format in your result

Comment: the data type is varchar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Giorgos pointed out, you appear to be storing your dates using a text type rather than a date type.  *Never* do this.  But, since you have, you can use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert the text into date when doing comparisons.

Another problem you had is that you were selecting non-aggregate columns in your `GROUP BY` query.

```
SELECT Emp_loc, Emp_Cat, FORMAT(MIN(Amount),2) As Amount
FROM tbl_remit
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(AP_from, '%m/%Y') <= '2015-01-01' AND
      STR_TO_DATE(AP_to, '%m/%Y')   <= '2015-01-01' AND
      Emp_Cat = 'PRIVATE'
GROUP BY Emp_Loc, Emp_Cat
```

Comment: yes i did. Sorry, I'll clean up my records first. but thank you for this sir :)

Comment: Sir, what's the reason behind the GROUP BY Emp_Loc, Emp_Cat?

Comment: If you want to select `Emp_Cat` it has to either appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or it must be inside an aggregate function.  I chose the former because that seemed to make the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

ap_from and ap_to are DATE type?
Then try this

```
SELECT Emp_loc, Emp_Cat, FORMAT(SUM(Amount),2) As Amount
FROM tbl_remit
WHERE YEAR(AP_from) = 2015 AND YEAR(AP_To) = 2015 AND Emp_Cat = 'PRIVATE'
GROUP BY Emp_Loc
```

Comment: seems ap_from and ap_to are **Not**  DATE type

Comment: yes it is not. I'll clean up my records first and use this.